# Unable to show some label and image view in iPad

Tags: ios, xcode6

When I build my app on iPhone, then it works fine.
But when I build it on iPad, some Labels and some ImageViews are not showing.

I have checked to fix its origin on iPhone and iPad.

This issue occurred after updating Xcode 6.

Before updating Xcode 6 it was working fine on both iPhone and iPad.

So where am I wrong?

Comment: check with the autoLayout/autoresize.

Comment: when add label in another view then it's not showing. if it add in self.view it shows.

Comment: is that second View  where you are added ? and check the frame.

Comment: @VinodJadhav, me too. Labels on iPad are not show immediately and labels on iPod shows immediately. Did you get a solution bro ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43289978/some-label-texts-are-not-show-immediately-in-ipad

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **Debug View Hierarchy** button to figure out where are your labels and images : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debugger/using_view_debugger/using_view_debugger.html